# Entypo icons not working in chrome v32?

Tags: google-chrome

Not all characters in entypo font in Chrome v32 (32.0.1700.76 m) on Windows 8.1 x64 render correctly. In previous versions it was fine. Please see the character map yourself. http://www.entypo.com/characters/

[image: Screenshot of entypo character map]

It also doesn't display correctly in 34.0.1809.0 canary. Do you know what might be causing this issue? Is it just me or is it every chrome user?

Comment: Same for me, been searching a bit but haven't found a solution yet.
I'm also running win 8.1 and the same version of chrome, also tried canary but the same thing occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after giving up on searching, I decided to try some things on my own.
And I got the font to work using this fix below, in order to render fonts properly in Google Chrome.

The fix:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   @font-face {
      font-family: 'entypo';
      src: url('path to entypo.svg#entypo') format('svg');
   }
}
```

Comment: Great! I actually found these commented lines in my fontello.css file with a comment:
`/* Chrome hack: SVG is rendered more smooth in Windozze. 100% magic, uncomment if you need it. */
/* Note, that will break hinting! In other OS-es font will be not as sharp as it could be */`

Comment: Haven't seen any problems so far on Windows 7/8.1 and OSX so I don't know why they commented it.